# Why the function ScalingFunctions does not work?

Tags: graphics, parametric-functions

Why highlighted in red and does not work function `ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}` in [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)?

```
ParametricPlot[{0.06677273831511694*(1 - E^(-8.145*t)),
  -0.10917030600597447*(1 - E^(-8.145*t)) + 1.2031921424186618*t},
 {t, 0, 2.6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {0., 3.0191292643518968`}},
 AspectRatio -> 1, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}]
```

Comment: The option is not implemented for `ParametricPlot`. Compare `Options[Plot, ScalingFunctions]` with `Options[ParametricPlot, ScalingFunctions]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) is not documented to work with [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot), I think that is only because it fails when using it together with a [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) option. Take a look at the result of your [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot):

```
ParametricPlot[
    {
    0.06677273831511694*(1-E^(-8.145*t)),
    -0.10917030600597447*(1-E^(-8.145*t))+1.2031921424186618*t
    },
    {t,0,2.6},
    PlotRange->{{0,0.07},{0.,3.0191292643518968`}},
    AspectRatio->1,
    ScalingFunctions->{None,"Reverse"}
]
```

[image]

Notice that the vertical plot range is actually `{0, -3}` and not `{0, 3}`. So, either remove the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) option:

```
ParametricPlot[
    {
    0.06677273831511694*(1-E^(-8.145*t)),
    -0.10917030600597447*(1-E^(-8.145*t))+1.2031921424186618*t
    },
    {t,0,2.6},
    AspectRatio->1,
    ScalingFunctions->{None,"Reverse"}
]
```

[image]

or modify it to reflect the transform being used:

```
ParametricPlot[
    {
    0.06677273831511694*(1-E^(-8.145*t)),
    -0.10917030600597447*(1-E^(-8.145*t))+1.2031921424186618*t
    },
    {t,0,2.6},
    PlotRange->{{0,0.07},{0.,-3.0191292643518968`}},
    AspectRatio->1,
    ScalingFunctions->{None, "Reverse"}
]
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use `PlotRange -> All`.

Answer (score 3):

`ScalingFunctions` is not an option `ParametricPlot`.

To get the desired look, you can post-process the output of `ParametricPlot` to vertically flip the coordinates of line objects (using `ScalingTransform[{1,-1}]`) and reverse the vertical axis tick labels using `` Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"] ``:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{0.06677273831511694*(1 - E^(-8.145*t)),
      -0.10917030600597447*(1 - E^(-8.145*t)) + 1.2031921424186618*t},
    {t, 0, 2.6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {0., 3.0191292643518968`}},
    AspectRatio -> 1] /. Line[a_] :> Line[ScalingTransform[{1, -1}]@a], 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"]}]
```

[image]